# With Amazon SES is it possible to restrict SMTP credentials to specific sender email addresses in one AWS account?

Tags: amazon-ses

I am planning to transition some email SMTP use to Amazon's SES.  I have several domains and sender email addresses verified with SES and am testing in the sandbox.

From what I can tell, SES SMTP credentials are not tied to any specific domain or sender email address within my AWS account.

Is this correct?

There is no mention of a domain or email address when generating the SMTP credentials, and in my initial testing I can use any of my SMTP credentials with any of my verified sending email addresses.

Is there a way to have a set of SES SMTP credentials that only work with one domain, or only with one sending email address?  It would seem that the alternative is to segregate your sending email addresses out to separate AWS accounts if you want to have SMTP credentials that only work with some email addresses and not others.  Why would that be the design?  It feels so odd that I suspect I am not understanding something around the intentions behind the relationship between the SES SMTP credentials and sender email addresses and domains.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently AWS does not support the above separate SMTP credentials for particular domains. Depending on the amount of domains you are planning to use you can create separate AWS accounts and tie the SMTP credentials to those domains.

Comment: This does not seem to be the correct answer

Answer (score 11):

Setting a custom Inline Policy on your IAM user can accomplish this:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ses:FromAddress": "do-not-reply@example.com"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I think you can do wildcards as well (`*.example.com`).

Comment: Worked for me to restrict an iam user to send emails through amazon SES SMTP credentials with only 1 email address.

Comment: If you want to use a wildcard, you need to use `StringLike` instead of `StringEquals`

Answer (score 1):

> From what I can tell, SES SMTP credentials are not tied to any
>   specific domain or sender email address within my AWS account.

That's correct.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html

> You can't specify a particular Amazon SES resource in an IAM policy.
>   You only control access to Amazon SES actions. Therefore, Amazon SES
>   does not use Amazon Resource Names (ARNs), which identify resources in
>   a policy. When you write a policy to control access to Amazon SES
>   actions, you use * as the resource.